# Specification for System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, mono, clr

Where can I find the specification for System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations? I've had a look through ECMA-335 (both the .pdf and .zip) but I can't see anything concerning this namespace.

Specifically, I'm looking for details on the static method Validator.TryValidateObject() and the ValidationResult class, beyond what is available on MSDN. But, more generally, I'm interested to know where I can find the specifications of parts of the framework that aren't included in ECMA-335.

Comment: Ecma-335 only covers the runtime, CLR and jitter.  There is no additional spec or documentation beyond what MSDN provides.  Consider using the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/Validator.cs,134f7b7fcaa7149d).

Comment: Ah, thanks for that resource. So that implies that if Mono is inconsistent with .NET in a class that's not covered by Ecma-335, as long as the behaviour doesn't contradict the MSDN documentation it can't really be called a bug in Mono. Is that correct? (I'm currently seein such an inconsistency but I'm not sure if I should raise it with the Mono project)